# discord.py как выдавать временный мут

Tags: datetime, discord.py

подскажите как выдавать временный мут на сервере, можно конечно использовать await asyncio.sleep(), но проблема в топ что если бот выключится таймер сбросится и поэтому этот вариант не подходит, я думал сделать это с помощью библиотеки datetime, но не знаю как

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вот код:

---

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import sleep

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True, kick_members=True)
async def mute(ctx, user: discord.Member, time: int, reason):
    role = user.guild.get_role(1234567890) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер
    await ctx.send(f'{user} получил мут на {time} минут по причине: {reason}')
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await user.move_to(None)
    await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
    await user.remove_roles(role)
```

---

### З.Ы.

---

Там где "*role = user.guild.get_role(1234567890) # айди роли которую будет получать юзер*"
Замените "1234567890" на айди нужной роли

---

Чтобы мут не сбрасывался при выключении бота, я думаю можно использовать базу данных, которая будет обновляться через определённые промежутки времени с момента запуска бота, и при до выключения в БД сохранится последнее значение времени мута, и того что вообще кто-то замьючен. Дальше при запуске бота бот считывает из бд, что Ваня Иванов был замьючен на 10 минут и ему осталось молчать ещё 7 минут(последнее сохранённое значение)

Как по другому я не знаю